# Best source for sound effects?

Tags: sound, assets, sound-effects

What is a good source for sound effects for use in an indie game production (C#, XNA)?

- The sounds do not need to be free.
- They, however, should have a clear licence for commercial use.
- The website should allow for searching, browsing and preview (or better: pre-listening).

I already had a look at http://www.1soundfx.com but their collection is not too large. I am specifically looking for sound effects. No music and no ways to make my own sounds.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [FreeSound.org](http://freesound.org/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find free sounds for my game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8/where-can-i-find-free-sounds-for-my-game)

Comment: (I also think the question isn't constructive, since it's a 
"list-of-X" with no possible single answer).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use [SoundSnap.com](http://www.soundsnap.com) they are reputable and have been used by several major companies.

Answer (score 0):

An indie game might be a good place for some old school [self generated midi sound effects].[1](http://www.bfxr.net/).